# XCOPY is getting the folder structure but not copying any of the files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a batch file that XCopies (each on a separate line) a bunch of folders on one computer out to an external hard drive. They all appear to be working except the one that copies from a network share.

This is the XCOPY command:

```
Xcopy  "\\BRADHOME\Documents"  "F:\BradHome\Documents\"  /M /E /G /H /Y /C
```

I get the full folder structure, but no files. I have run it from the batch file, from Task Scheduler and tried the command directly from an elevated command prompt.

My first though was permissions issue, but I can access the share just fine from Windows Explorer and I am getting the folder structure so I don't think that is it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, just figured it out.

It was the archived attribute I set with the /M switch. I already backed up everything to another hard drive so it would not do it again to the new hard drive. So basically my plan of swapping hard drives every week to keep a backup off site needs some tweaking.